# Wordpress вывод произвольных типов записей через wp_query

Tags: wordpress, wp-query

Создан произвольный тип записей. Пытаюсь на главной вывести название рубрик этих записей + сами эти записи. Застрял на моменте фильтрации - как только не пробовал, но все равно выводятся либо все записи, либо вообще ничего. Необходимо чтобы было в таком виде:

Название категории -> все элементы этой категории

Бьюсь не один час уже :(

```
<section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <?php 
            $all_terms = get_terms( 'goods', array( 'hide_empty' => 1 ) );
            foreach (  $all_terms as $term ) {  
                $term_taxonomy_id = $term->term_id;
                $term = get_term( $term_taxonomy_id );
                $slug = $term->slug;
                
                //print_r( $term );
                
               echo "<div class='group' id='$term->slug'>
                <div class='group-title text-center mt-5'>
                    <h2>$term->name </h2>
                </div>
                <div class='swiper-container'>
                <div class='swiper-wrapper'>
                ";
                
                
                $args=array(
                     'post_type' => 'goods',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'taxonomy' => $slug
                    );
                print_r($args);
                $q = new WP_Query($args);
                if($q->have_posts()) {
                    /*
                     * затем запускаем цикл
                     */
                    while($q->have_posts()){ $q->the_post();
                                        
                        /*
                         * выводим например ссылку на каждый пост
                         */
                        echo "
                        
                        <div class='group-item d-flex flex-column align-items-center swiper-slide'>
                            <div class='group-item-left'>
                                <div class='group-item-img'>
                                    <img src='". get_field('фото') ."' alt='mask' class='img-fluid'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='group-item-right text-center'>
                                <div class='group-item-title mt-4'>
                                    <h3 class='group-item-title-h3'>".get_the_title()."</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class='group-item-star'>
                                    <img src='".get_template_directory_uri()."/img/icons/star.svg' alt='Рейтинг' class='img-fluid'>
                                </div>
                                <div class='group-item-descr'>
                                    ". get_field('описание') ."
                                </div>
                                <div class='group-item-price'>
                                    <span>". get_field('цена') ." </span> ₽
                                </div>
                                <div class='button-order mt-2'>
                                    <a href='#' class='btn zakaz-btn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#payment-request'>ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        ";
                            }
                    }

                
                /*
                 * восстанавливаем глобальную переменную $post
                 */
                wp_reset_postdata();
                echo "
                        </div>
                            <div class='swiper-pagination'></div>
                            <div class='swiper-button-prev'></div>
                            <div class='swiper-button-next'></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>";
                }
                    
            ?>
        
        
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Зря вы назвали post_type (пост тип) так же, как и таксономию и так же вы путаете taxonomy (таксономию) с term (термином). Можете подробнее почитать об этом в гугле. Но на примере WordPress post - это post_type, category - taxonomy, конкретная категория, например cat1 - term. Как делать выборку типов постов по конкретному термину

```
$q = new WP_Query ( [
    'post_type' => 'goods', // post_type name
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product' // taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'slug'
            'terms'    => $slug // slug of the term
        ]
] );
```

Comment: Я изменил post_type на product , вставил ваш код -ничего не поменялось - выводит в каждой категории все продукты, без фильтрации по слагу. Не понимаю, в чем причина.

Comment: Потому что этот код соответствует вопросу, там у вас goods

Answer (score 0):

Тоже самое было, через `id` не получалось фильтровать никак.

В итоге помог вариант через `slug`.

Answer (score -1):

Получилось сделать так:

```
$q = new WP_Query ( [
                    
                    'tax_query' => 
                        ['relation' => 'AND',
                        [
                            'taxonomy' => 'goods', // taxonomy name
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $slug // slug of the term
                        ],
                         ],
                    'post_type' => 'product', // post_type name
                    'order'     => 'ASC',
                ] );
```

Comment: Зачем это здесь? Ваш вариант отличается только типом поста. И он не соответствует вопросу. Это только замутняет содержание для других пользователей, которые ищут ответ на похожий вопрос.

Comment: Добавив 'relation' => 'AND' к запросу все отфильтровалось как надо, он мне вывел записи с типом поста product, таксономией goods и terms = $slug. Если не вписать это условие запрос выводил мне абсолютно все записи с типом поста product.

Comment: Ерунда какая-то. Он тут не нужен. Если без него не работает, значит, у вас где-то кривой фильтр pre_get_posts.

Comment: WP чистый, плагин CPT UI и ACF, больше ничего.

Comment: А кастомный пост создан в CPT?

Comment: Да,и пост и таксономия

Comment: И об этом в вопросе ни слова. А ведь, похоже, только поэтому вам тут требуется AND, который абсолютно не нужен в голом WP.